# how to bind TextView to ViewHolder

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to bind a TextView onto my ViewHolder and cant quite figure out what I'm doing wrong. I am only having trouble with the two lines of code under the commented out title, User Crumbs. It looks like it should work but Java is telling me it expects an expression
here is my code:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BreadSliceViewHolder holder, int position) {
    /****************
     * User Icon *
     ****************/
    int userNameId = 0;
    userNameId = ViewHolderUtilities
            .getUserIcon(userNameId);
    holder.bind(position);
    holder.iconView.setImageResource(userNameId);

    /****************
     * User Crumbs*
     ****************/

    String crumbsString = TextView;
    holder.numberOfCrumbs.setText(crumbsString);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mBreadSliceItems;
}

public interface BreadSliceClickListener {
    void onBreadSliceClick(int clickedItemIndex);
}

class BreadSliceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {
    final ImageView iconView;
    final ImageView crumbImageView;


    final TextView listItemBreadView;
    final TextView numberOfCrumbs;
    final TextView viewHolderIndex;


    BreadSliceViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        iconView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_icon);
        crumbImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.crumb_imageView);

        numberOfCrumbs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.number_of_crumbs);
        listItemBreadView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        viewHolderIndex = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.total_distance);


        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
String crumbsString = TextView;
```

Do not know where from do you pull crumbsString value, not enough code to understand that. But it should not be a TextView class ).

Answer (score 0):

Change this `String crumbsString = TextView;` to this : `String crumbsString = TextView.getText();`